# Getting error when trying to use fflib

Tags: fflib

I am trying to learn fflib, in this i do have 3 layers Service, selector and domain level. I am getting a list of opportunity records to display on VF page using selector and I have added all these records to a wapper class with boolen now I want to delete some records. From my service class i am calling domain class and trying to delete, when I try to delete I am a getting an error that

> Invalid conversion from runtime type OpportunitySelectorImp to IOpportunityDomain

Can anyone help me to fix this error. 
My code:

Controller :

```
public with sharing class oppController{

public List<oppWrapperClass> oppWrapper {get; set;}

public oppController(){ 
    oppWrapper = new List<oppWrapperClass>();
    OpportunityService opp = new OpportunityService();
    for(Opportunity oppSoqlResult : opp.getOpportunityInfo(5)){
        oppWrapper.add(new oppWrapperClass(oppSoqlResult, false));
    }
}

public class oppWrapperClass{
    public Boolean     action {get; set;}
    public Opportunity opp    {get; set;}
    public oppWrapperClass(Opportunity opp, Boolean action){
        this.opp    = opp;
        this.action = action;
    }
}

@RemoteAction
public static string getActionIds(List<Id> actionIds){
    System.debug('action Ids : ' + actionIds);
    OpportunityService opp = new OpportunityService();
    Boolean result = opp.getdeleteOpp(actionIds);
    System.debug('Result : ..' + result );
    System.debug('Call from opp controller for delete' );
    return null;
}}
```

Service class:

```
public class OpportunityService{

public OpportunityService(){}

public List<Opportunity> getOpportunityInfo(Integer Values){
    return service().getOpportunityInfo(Values);
} 

public Boolean getdeleteOpp(List<id> oppID){
    System.debug('Call from getdeleteOpp for delete' );
    return service().getdeleteOpp(oppID);
}

private static IOpportunityService service(){
    System.debug('Call from IOpportunityService for delete' );
    return (IOpportunityService) Application.Service.newInstance(IOpportunityService.class);
}  
}
```

Service implement:

```
public class OpportunityServiceImp implements IOpportunityService{
public OpportunityServiceImp(){}

public List<Opportunity> getOpportunityInfo(Integer Amount){

    fflib_ISObjectUnitOfWork uow = Application.UnitOfWork.newInstance();  
    List<Opportunity> oppResult = OpportunitySelectorImp.newInstance().opportunityInfoSelector(Amount);
    return oppResult;   
}

public Boolean getdeleteOpp(List<ID> oppIDs){

    List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();
    for(Id oppId : oppIDs){
        Opportunity opps = new Opportunity();
        opps.id = oppId;
        oppList.add(opps);
    }

    System.debug('Call from getdeleteOpp for delete in OpportunityServiceImp ' + oppList );
    fflib_ISObjectUnitOfWork uow = Application.UnitOfWork.newInstance();
    Boolean result = OpportunitesDomainImp.newInstance().deleteOpportunity(oppList);
    //System.debug('opp result : ' + result ); 
    return result;
}}
```

Selector implement :

```
public with sharing class OpportunitySelectorImp extends fflib_SObjectSelector implements IOpportunitySelector{

public static IOpportunitySelector newInstance(){
   return (IOpportunitySelector) Application.Selector.newInstance(Opportunity.SObjectType);
}

public List<Schema.SObjectField> getSObjectFieldList(){
   return new List<Schema.SObjectField>{
       Opportunity.Name,
       Opportunity.Id,
       Opportunity.Amount
   };
}

public Schema.SObjectType getSObjectType(){
   return Opportunity.sObjectType; 
}

public List<Opportunity> opportunityInfoSelector(Integer Amount){

    fflib_QueryFactory opportunityQueryFactory = newQueryFactory(); 

    return Database.query(opportunityQueryFactory.selectField('OrderNumber__c').setLimit(Amount).toSOQL());
    //List <opportunity> opportunityInfo = [SELECT ];
    //return null;
}}
```

Domain implement :

```
public with sharing class OpportunitesDomainImp extends fflib_SObjectDomain implements IOpportunityDomain{
//public OpportunityDomainImp(){}


public static IOpportunityDomain newInstance(){
   return (IOpportunityDomain) Application.Selector.newInstance(Opportunity.SObjectType);
}

public OpportunitesDomainImp(List<Opportunity> sObjectList){
    // Domain classes are initialised with lists to enforce bulkification throughout
    super(sObjectList);
}

public Boolean deleteOpportunity(List<Opportunity> oppDeleteLst){
    System.debug('Call from deleteOpportunity for delete in OpportunitesDomainImp ' + oppDeleteLst);
    Database.DeleteResult[] DR_Dels = DataBase.delete(oppDeleteLst);
    /* 
        for (Database.DeleteResult dr:drl){
        if(!dr.isSuccess())
            Database.Error err = dr.getErrors()[0];
        }
    */
    return DR_Dels[0].isSuccess();
} }
```

Please guide me.

Comment: N.B. a domain class should probably not implement a delete method; that would the the responsibility of `OpportunitiesService.delete(Set<Id> ids)`

Answer (score 4):

The error is in your domain implement file, instead of getting newInstance of Domain, you are getting Selector.

Change this

```
public static IOpportunityDomain newInstance(){
   return (IOpportunityDomain) Application.Selector.newInstance(Opportunity.SObjectType);
}
```

Into this:

```
public static IOpportunityDomain newInstance(){
   return (IOpportunityDomain) Application.Domain.newInstance(Opportunity.SObjectType);
}
```

I also noted that you are not making use of Unit Of Work you created in your service implement. You can simply do uow.registerDeleted method call instead of Database.delete.